# Ignore case in SQL Server replace

Tags: sql-server, replace

Is the anyway to ignore case in SQL server's replace so:

```
Declare @replaceword = 'test'

REPLACE(@var,@replaceword,'<i>' + @replaceword + '</i>')
```

So if `@var` was `'Test test'`

It world return

```
'<i>Test</i> <i>test</i>'
```

Comment: As an aside, this depends upon the collation you created the table with (it may be inherited from the SQL Server installation). The database I work with is all case-insensitive by default with only a few explicit case sensitive columns.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How REPLACE()  matches things is determined by the specific *collation* in use. Different collations may have different comparison rules. If you take a look at the REPLACE() documentation, you'll see an example near the bottom of how to specify a specific collation:

> SELECT    REPLACE('Das ist ein Test'  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,
>   'Test', 'desk' )

I'm not familiar enough with the different possible collations to know which you will need, but this should point you down the correct path.

Unfortunately, I suspect this still may not be enough. When you replace, you really do *replace* the matched text. You don't *merge* the matched text.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to have to do something like this:

```
Declare @replaceword1 varchar(100)
Declare @replaceword2 varchar(100)

select @replaceword1 = 'test'
select @replaceword2 = 'Test'


select REPLACE(
    REPLACE('Test test',@replaceword1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS,'<i>' +
    @replaceword1 + '</i>'),
    @replaceword2 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS,'<i>' + @replaceword2 + '</i>')
```

Note: This forces a case-sensitive replace: `SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS`

`CS` in a collation name refers to case-sensitive.

`CI` in a collation name refers to case-insensitive.

For more information on [collation naming](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx).

Comment: It might be worth adding that the `CS` (or `CI`) in the collation string means case-sensitive (or case insensitive).